# qdbus over TCP on mobile

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, dbus, qdbus

I have running services (written in c++) communicating with each other by dbus on a linux host, and everything is working great.
I was wondering if It's even possible to communicate with those dbus'es over TCP from mobile phones (iOS and Android) using qdbus lib?
Is this lib suitable for that? If not how to approach this problem?

I tried to change session-local.conf file to listen on some port and test it a bit, but I'm not even sure if it even makes sense and if it will even work on mobile.

Comment: So, you want everyone in the world to be able to send messages and commands to local applications? This will end in tears.